# How to convert a map to Json string in kotlin?

Tags: java, json, kotlin, dictionary, gson

I have a mutableMap,

```
    val invoiceAdditionalAttribute = mutableMapOf<String, Any?>()
    invoiceAdditionalAttribute.put("clinetId",12345)
    invoiceAdditionalAttribute.put("clientName", "digital")
    invoiceAdditionalAttribute.put("payload", "xyz")
```

I want to convert it into json string

the output should be,

```
"{\"clinetId\"=\"12345\", \"clientName\"=\"digital\", \"payload\"=\"xyz\"}"
```

Currently, I am using Gson library,

```
val json = gson.toJson(invoiceAdditionalAttribute)
```

and the output is

```
{"clinetId":12345,"clientName":"digital","payload":"xyz"}
```

Comment: Whats's wrong with the method you are using? `"{\"clinetId\"=\"12345\", \"clientName\"=\"digital\", \"payload\"=\"xyz\"}" ` - this is not a json string. JSON has it's own formatting pattern, and that string doesn't adher to it. `gson.toJson(invoiceAdditionalAttribute)` - is the right method to use to get json string.

Comment: The output looks right to me, also I've never seen = in a json string

Comment: The output is right. The output you want(invalid json) is with `"` escaped(`"\""`) to be a valid String for Java. If you really want to escape it, you can do `String escapedJson = json.replaceAll("\"", "\\\\\"");`

Comment: You can use [StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJava-java.lang.String-) for string escaping

Answer (score 4):

The right [json formatting string](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_syntax.asp) is:

```
{"clinetId":12345,"clientName":"digital","payload":"xyz"}
```

So this is the right method to get it:

```
val json = gson.toJson(invoiceAdditionalAttribute)
```

If you want a string formatted like this:

```
{"clinetId"=12345, "clientName"="digital", "payload"="xyz"}
```

just replace `:` with `=`:

```
val json = gson.toJson(invoiceAdditionalAttribute).replace(":", "=")
```

But if you truly want to have a string with backslashes and `clinetId` value to be inside quotes:

```
val invoiceAdditionalAttribute = mutableMapOf<String, Any?>()
invoiceAdditionalAttribute["clinetId"] = 12345.toString()
invoiceAdditionalAttribute["clientName"] = "digital"
invoiceAdditionalAttribute["payload"] = "xyz"

val json = gson.toJson(invoiceAdditionalAttribute)
        .replace(":", "=")
        .replace("\"", "\\\"")
```

EDIT:

As pointed int he comments `.replace(":", "=")` can be fragile if some string values contain a ":" character.
To avoid it I would write a custom extension function on `Map<String, Any?>`:

```
fun Map<String, Any?>.toCustomJson(): String = buildString {
    append("{")
    var isFirst = true
    this@toCustomJson.forEach {
        it.value?.let { value ->
            if (!isFirst) {
                append(",")
            }
            isFirst = false
            append("\\\"${it.key}\\\"=\\\"$value\\\"")
        }
    }

    append("}")
}

// Using extension function

val customJson = invoiceAdditionalAttribute.toCustomJson()
```

Comment: `.replace(":", "=")` can be fragile if some string values contain a ":" character.